I accidentally threw away my 4th 3D Printing bed gear on my Creality Ender Pro 3, what can I use instead?

I am an owner of a Creality Ender 3 Pro 3D; I got it 2 years ago. I accidently threw away my 4th black gear belonging to my Creality Ender 3 Pro.
When I try to home it, it keeps getting an error, I tried searching my room to find it, but I did not find it, I think I threw it away and I wonder what to do? Is there anything around the house I can try to substitute for it, or can I find this part online?

The part you cannot find is a levelling wheel, it is nothing more than a fancy holder for an encapsulated nut.

So, in the spirit of 3D printing, you could just use an M3 nut (and washer) to come up with a makeshift solution, level the bed with a small wrench and print a replacement with a captive nut.
Or the lazy approach is to buy a replacement. You see them all over the Chinese marketplace websites but you could source it locally/domestically.
